# AngularJS: How to handle keyboard shortcuts in routing controllers?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router, keyboard-shortcuts

How do you implement page-specific **keyboard shortcuts** in an AngularJS 1.5 app that uses **routing**?

This is what I would like to achieve:

**index.html:**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html data-ng-app="myApp">
<body data-ng-keydown="onKeyDown($event)">
    ...
    <div data-ng-view></div>
    ...
</body>
</html>
```

As I understand, you need to handle key-down events on the `&lt;body&gt;` tag, if you don't have elements in the scope that are focused (input fields for example, I don't have those).

**app.js:**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'myControllers']);

myApp.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'pages/home.html',
            controller: 'HomeCtrl'
        })
        .when('/create', {
            templateUrl: 'pages/create.html',
            controller: 'CreateCtrl'
        });
}]);
```

**controllers.js:**

```js
var myControllers = angular.module('myControllers', []);

myControllers.controller('HomeCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

    $scope.closeLandingPagePopUp = function () {
        ...
    };

    $scope.onKeyDown = function ($event) {
        switch ($event.keyCode) {
            case 27: // [Esc]
                $scope.closeLandingPagePopUp();
                break;
            ...
        }
    };
}]);

myControllers.controller('CreateCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

    $scope.cancelCreation = function () {
        ...
    };

    $scope.onKeyDown = function ($event) {
        switch ($event.keyCode) {
            case 27: // [Esc]
                $scope.cancelCreation();
                break;
            ...
        }
    };
}]);
```

So on both pages the [Esc] key should be handled differently.

Of course the HTML attribute `data-ng-keydown="onKeyDown($event)"` doesn't work, because it's outside the controllers' scopes.

Is there a way to do this while still **keeping all page specific code within their respective controller?**

Comment: you should use small directives not controllers for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[georgeawg's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36267695/1483261) was inspiring, but I ended up with this implementation:

```
myControllers.controller('HomeCtrl', ['$scope', '$document', function ($scope, $document) {

    var handleKeyDown = function(event) {
        switch (event.keyCode) {
            case 27: // [Esc]
                $scope.closeLandingPagePopUp();
                break;
            ...
        }
        $scope.$apply();
    };
    $document.on('keydown', handleKeyDown);

    $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
        $document.unbind('keydown', handleKeyDown);
    });
}]);
```

There is actually nothing to do within the HTML parts.

**Explanation:**

1. Every controller has a `handleKeyDown(event)` function that implements the shortcuts
2. `$document.on('keydown', handleKeyDown)`binds the handler function to global keydown events when the controller is initialized. [$document](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$document) is Angular's jQuery wrapper.
3. Unbind the handler when the controller get's destroyed
4. Use `$scope.$apply()` to let Angular know when data has changed and the view needs to be refreshed

Answer (score 1):

### Global Keydown Directive

To get events outside of a directive, bind the event handler to `$document`.

```
angular.module('myApp').directive("globalKeydown", 
  function($document) {
    return function linkFn(scope,elem,attrs) {
        var handlerUnbind = $document.on("keydown", function(e) {
            scope.$eval(attrs.globalKeydown, {$event: e});
            scope.$apply();
        });
        scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
             handlerUnbind();
        })
    }
});
```

This example directive puts a `keydown` event handler on the `$document` that invokes the expression defined by the `global-event` attribute. The event is as exposed as `$event`.

### Example Usage

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
   <p>Click this window and press any key</p>
   <p global-keydown='keycode=($event.code)'>
      Global keydown = {{keycode}}
   </p>
</div>
```

The [DEMO on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zkfumpcj/).

For more information on `$event`, see [AngularJS Developer Guide -- $event](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#-event-).